# how to use form data every second with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm very confused. Can anyone help me?
Here is the code:

index.php =>

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function chk(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"test.php",
            data:{name:name},
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                $('#msg').html(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    setInterval (function chk() , 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return chk();return false;">

</form>

<p id="msg">Loading</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and test.php =>

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];// $name is constant for each request that submited from ajax($name is a parameter)


$api -> new server_data();  

$results = $api ->show($name); 

print_r($result);//This data updates from server in every second
```

=======================================================================

I'm trying to connect to an API, but in that API, data changes every second and I have to see these changes. On the other hand, I have to set default values with the form.

But the problem is here that each time the form submits, the posted value in test.php will be null, and the ajax request will not work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: When I copy your code locally, as is, it seems to work fine for me (I created index.php and pasted your contents, and test.php and pasted your contents, and placed that specific version of jQuery in the same directory - that was literally all I did). If I type in "test" in the name field, the PHP code responds accordingly with "test is &nbsp;test", and prints it out as HTML to the `#msg` element, as expected. The only thing I can think of at the moment is if your server is disallowing POST requests to that page. If you change to GET, does it appear in the `$_GET` array? What version of PHP?

Comment: dont forget your javascript function is asynchonous so you can spam request over each other.

Comment: the form submit is not the problem.the problem is,when im trying to use default value of test after that submit with ajax (for requesting data that changes every second) the test value changes to null.thank you

Comment: What do you mean by the default value of test? There's nothing like that in the code you posted.

Comment: the value that posted with form

Comment: .I have to extract data from server with the default value but when im trying to post the value to api page after following request the value set to null and api crashe.and blank

Comment: Look in the browser devtools network tab for any problems or unexpected stuff being sent to or received from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `name` attribute to your name input box element.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
```

Your PHP `$_POST['name']` variable is looking for an input element with the html attribute `name="name"`, whereas you only had an html attribute `id="name"`.

Source: [PHP: Dealing with Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: Their `<form>` doesn't have an action, though, and the submit function is returning false preventing the `<form>` from submitting to the same page. Really, it's pointless to even have the `<form>` element on there, it's not doing anything currently. They are just using $.ajax with an object `{name: name}`, which defines the variable name as `name` within the POST array (so `$_POST['name']` should read it).